# ¿Cómo verificar si realice un fetch en Git?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, git

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el que usamos la **librería simple-git** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git) para **ejecutar *Git* mediante *JavaScript***.

Hay una funcionalidad en especifico que sirve para hacer fetch a un repositorio. Lo que buscamos con la siguiente función es comprobar que la rama(branch) existe en el repositorio remoto(repoPath) y de no existir crearla:

```
export function fetch(repoPath, branch) {
git.fetch(repoPath, "feature/mocks")
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        console.log("La rama existe");
        git.checkout("feature/mocks")

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("No existe la rama");
        git.checkout("feature/mocks", ["-b"]);
        console.log(error)
    })
```

}

Pero no he podido saber como comprobar que efectivamente se esté realizando el fetch (sí únicamente le estamos pasando la ruta del repositorio remoto y no tenemos uno local) o sí realmente crea la rama cuando esta no existe. Solamente lo he medio probado por medio de console.log().

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo probar de una manera más certera si esta función sí se está ejecutando correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se ve en el [README.md del proyecto](https://github.com/steveukx/git-js#api), el método `fetch`  debiera invocarse como:

| API | What it Does |
| --- | --- |
| .fetch(remote, branch, handlerFn) | update the local working copy database with changes from a remote repo |

En este caso, usándolo como promesa:

```
git.fetch(remote, branch)
   .then(...)
   .catch(...)
```

El `remote` *puede* ser la URL del repo, pero lo corriente es usar el alias del remoto en `.git/config`:

```
 git.fetch('origin', 'feature/mocks')
```

Por debajo ejecuta

```
 git fetch origin feature/mocks
```

**1.- Si no tienes una copia local:**

> sí únicamente le estamos pasando la ruta del repositorio remoto y no tenemos uno local

Fallaría igual que si ejecutas `git fetch <cualquier cosa>` si no tienes un repo local. Tira un error

```
 fatal: no es un repositorio git
```

Y SimpleGit te dirá lo mismo.

**2. Si la rama remota no existe**

Cuando usas

```
 git.checkout(rama, ["-b"])
```

Por debajo ejecuta

```
 git checkout feature/mocks -b
```

Y eso tira un error. Lo que funcionaría ahí es

```
git.checkout({"-b": rama})
```

que por debajo ejecuta

```
 git checkout -b feature/mocks
```

**3. Cómo saber si el checkout funcionó**

Tanto si encuentra la rama como si no, tú estás ejecutando `git.checkout(...)`, que devuelve una promesa, pero no lo estás retornando. Eso provoca que el fracaso de la segunda operación fallaría silenciosamente.

Tendrías que retornar el resultado de cualquiera de los dos checkout. Por ejemplo si reescribieras la función como

```
function fetch(remoto, rama) {

    return git.fetch(remoto, rama)
       .then(res => {
          console.log('éxito!', {resultado:res});
          return git.checkout(rama);
       })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            return git.checkout({ "-b": rama });
        });
}
```

Podrías manejar el resultado con

```
fetch('origin', 'feature/mocks')
    .then(res => {
          console.log('éxito!', {resultado:res});
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Cuando una rama no existe la consola informará el error

```
GitError: fatal: no se puedo encontrar ref remota feature/mocks
```

Y más abajo:

```
éxito! { resultado: '' }
```

(Como podrás ver, en caso de éxito la salida es un string vacío)